# Extract values from a list of IO actions

Tags: haskell, monads

So I've got something like:

```
[IO Blah, IO Blah, IO Blah]
```

and I really want just a list of `Blah`s, how can I do it?

P.S.: Yes, I am working within an IO function.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence).

> Evaluate each action in the sequence from left to right, and collect the results.

```
do blahs <- sequence listOfIoBlah
   -- now use blahs
```

Answer (score 10):

[Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle) can be very useful in answering these sort of questions, *if* you know how to formulate the question as a type, for example: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5BIO+a%5D+-%3E+IO+%5Ba%5D

Answer (score 8):

What you want is `sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`. It works as you expect: All actions are executed in order, the results are gathered and returned. Please notice, that nothing is returned unless all command are finished.